# React. Recursive component

Tags: reactjs, recursion, components

There is a component `Child` which is recursively invokes himself. Also the component has local state, for example, `state = { isOpen: false }`. This `Child` components wraps in a `Parent` component. So, we have one parent component with recursively generated child components (with their local state). The question is: How can I get access to specific `Child` component to invoke setState from the `Parent`  component. Or how can I store recursively created components states inside `Parent`.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see how recursion would change the situation.  You normally just define a method on the parent class that changes the state through `setState`, and then pass that method down to the child (after binding it).  I don't think recursion would change anything.

Comment: @whs.bsmith If I declare property in parent state `isOpen` and pass this property to the child component does this mean that `isOpen` property will be the same for all child components which was created recursively? Am I wrong?

Comment: As i thought, `isOpen` will be the same for all `Child` components. https://codesandbox.io/s/0gm6Rr0DV. The question still open...

Comment: why dont you pass the isOpen as props ?

Comment: @AshKander In that example I tried to show that @whs.bsmith solution doesn't work for me. I looking for 'workaround' how can I manage children recursive components from my parent to decouple smart component from dumb. If you have any suggestion feel free to help me :) 

**P.S.** I am going to create tree-view structure and manage all `onClick`, `onKeyPress`, `onDoubleClick` event handles from my parent component. But if I do this, I can't get access to function which inside children component that make expande/collapse functionality for me.

Comment: here is an updated version of your sandbox with the toggle function in wrapper.js > https://codesandbox.io/s/wpLwDzg6r

Comment: @AshKander Ehm... It seems that I overwrote you example on sand box. Could you please provide me link to you sandbox instead of my?

Comment: well the link in my previous comment still seems ok :o

Comment: @AshKander Your example works, but I'm not sure that `forceUpdate()` is a good solution. _Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render() (c) React spec._  Anyway, thank you for your example it brought me to a couple of thoughts.

Comment: youre right about the force update, but since your state contains a tree structure... TBH your initial solution sounded good to me :p

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way:

```
const Asterics= ({i}) => [
  <b>*</b>,
  i>0 && <RAsterics i={i-1}/>
]
const RAsterics = (props)=><Asterics {...props}/>

export default Asterics
```

(React <16 instead)

```
const Asterics= ({i}) => <div>
    <b>*</b>
    {i>0 && <RAsterics i={i-1}/>}
</div>
const RAsterics = (props)=><Asterics {...props}/>
```

Then, whenever you need it:

```
<Asterics i={10}/>
```